# Display a different Post Detail Page Than Post Template

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

A bit of background:

I've build a social media aggregator that pulls in a bunch of different custom post types.

Based on the post type I'm assigning a template dynamically for the list view. So each post type has a unique look.

```
                    switch (get_post_type())
                {
                    case twitter:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'twitter' );break;
                    case flickr:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'flickr' );break;
                    case facebook:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'facebook' );break;
                    case youtube:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'youtube' );break;
                    case instagram:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'instagram' );break;
                    case googleplus:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'googleplus' ); break;
                    case facebook:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'facebook' ); break;
                    case linkedin:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'linkedin' ); break;
                    case pinterest:
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'pinterest' ); break;

                    default:
                        get_template_part( 'content_blog');
                }?>
```

What I want to do is to link the "more" button which takes the user to a standardized detail page that looks the same for all post types.

Is there a way to set the "Post Detail" formatting independently of its respective template.

Is there a best practices way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want for the code below to link to some different URL.

```
 <?php the_content( 'Read more ...' ); ?>
```

If so, then you can check [this WordPress Forum Question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-more-tag-url?replies=5)  which shows how to achieve this.

Also one point about your `switch` statement:

Instead of using `switch` why don't you just rename **content_blog.php** to **content.php** and then use this single line of code:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The switch command is because some post types may share a template though none do yet.